# two floats still rounding after conversion?

Tags: c#, math, floating-point, division, truncation

So, I've been trying to take two floats and divide them, but it seems like it always gives me a 0 or infinite.

I know this happens with integers (but I'm using floats). It seems like its being truncated somewhere in my conversions. i know this is kinda crappy code, but I did once before, I just don't recall how and it was also very poorly done.

So i hope someone can show me the correct way to divide two vars of float type.

I want to have a float that will be increasing per day based on a given input.

The default for amount is set at `1.23456789`. But it seems i am always given a `0` or `00` after trying to divide them as a converted variable since I can manually input the floats values and it seems to be just fine.

```
string charc = Settings.Default["Day"].ToString();
DateTime checkme = DateTime.Parse(charc);
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string daysleft = (checkme - now).Days.ToString();
float.TryParse(daysleft, out float daysnum);
textBox3.Text = daysnum.ToString();

float amount = Settings.Default["Amount"];
float Total = amount / daysnum;
```

Comment: Please note this is a **C#** code, it would help to mention it and tag.

Comment: This code has more holes than the Titanic... In fact the Titanic looks unsinkable when compared to this

Comment: Given `I can manually input the floats values and it seems to be just fine.` then it's probably a truncation during conversion at some point.  You're using a lot of `string` intermediates, for no apparent reason.  Convert to string only when you need a string.  You can cast integers directly to float.

Comment: oh, well LOL that makes more sense, however to me it also looks scary, anywho yeah i see now, does point me in the right direction, ill go look up some more on refactoring and will aviod being so messing in the future.

Comment: The main point of all the conversions was to set textboxes, but i just did it in a horrible way LOL will fix thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Notes**

- You should really consider naming your variables more concisely
- If something is string and you need to parse it, check for errors
- You also had all sorts of conversions and tom-foolery going on

However this should point you in the right direction

**Code Refactored**

```
var dayString = Settings.Default["Day"].ToString()); // Some day From Settings

if (!DateTime.TryParse(dayString, out var someDay))
{
   throw new ApplicationException($"Invalid input date : {dayString}");
   //return; // return if not a valid date stored in settings
}

var daysLeft = ( DateTime.Now - someDay).Days; // days left as int (number)

textBox3.Text = daysleft.ToString();

var amountString = Settings.Default["Amount"]; // Some amount From Settings

if (!double.TryParse(amountString, out var amount))
{
   throw new ApplicationException($"Invalid input Amount : {amountString}");
    //  return; // return if not a valid double stored in settings
}

var total = amount / daysLeft;
```

Updated to throw an `ApplicationException` if your input cant be parsed. At least it will show you something went wrong and why

Comment: Rather then writing your own exceptions (wich has a lot of things to consider: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET), you should start with just letting the .NET ones come out. Parse is happy to throw exceptions, sometiems too happy.. It's Exception throwing is often so vexing, TryParse was added as not-exception happy alternative.

Comment: @Christopher all good points, however the Exceptions were just away of minimising the next response, "It doesnt work!"

Comment: @TheHomie actually its a valid approach. you are just signifying something when wrong. Another one is throw an exception. another one is just return without continuing. it depends how far down the rabbit hole you want to go

Comment: If you do want to go down the Rabbit hole regarding exceptions, here are two articles worth reading (one I linked above already): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET They helped me getting to terms with handling Exceptions and thus far I never heard a complaint about them.